# how can I change sshd use another pam configuration in /etc/pam.d?

Tags: ssh, pam

I wan't to open another sshd on the server, the old one use default setting, and the new one use pam module

now I add an /etc/ssh/sshd_config2

and I think I should add a file /etc/pam.d/sshd2

how can I config sshd to use /etc/pam.d/sshd2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can just

```
ln -s /usr/sbin/sshd /usr/sbin/sshd2
```

and start /usr/sbin/sshd2 will use the config in /etc/pam.d/sshd2